# Can't seem to disable button

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I'm new to Visual Basic and I am stuck on a Tic Tac Toe exercise. Here is my code.

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Enum Buttons As Byte
        btn1 = 1
        btn2 = 2
        btn3 = 3
        btn4 = 4
        btn5 = 5
        btn6 = 6
        btn7 = 7
        btn8 = 8
        btn9 = 9
    End Enum

    Public Sub Computer()
        Dim RandomNumberGenerator As New Random
        Dim RandomNumber As Integer
        RandomNumber = RandomNumberGenerator.Next(1, 9)
        Dim RandomButton = CType(RandomNumber, Buttons)
        Do
            If RandomButton.Enabled = True Then
                RandomButton.Enabled = False
                RandomButton.Text = "O"
                RandomButton.Font = New Font("Consolas", 50, FontStyle.Bold)
                Exit Do
            Else
                RandomNumber = RandomNumberGenerator.Next(1, 9)
                Dim RandomButton = CType(RandomNumber, Buttons)
            End If
        Loop
```

The problem that I am having is the if loop. I am trying to see if the Random button selected is enabled or not. But instead Visual Basic tells me that "Enable is not a member of Tic_Tac_Toe.Fourm1.Buttons. I wanted to know if there is any way I can disable or enable a button via an enum. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: Your enum (Buttons) doesn't have a member "Enabled".  You are setting properties of a Button on an enum, which won't work.

You have to create an actual UI Button for each "RandomButton" and set the value, ID, and text, then add it to the form.  At this point you could get/set those properties, including "Enabled".

If these buttons are all on the Form already and you're just trying to pick a random one, you can use `Me.Controls.Find(ID)`

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. Even when I change it, it still shows the same error.

Comment: Take a look here for some examples of how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11312239/567202

Comment: I did have the UI Button on the form. Here is a picture of it. [link](http://postimg.org/image/tlovt61ap/)

Comment: Make sure each button has an ID, like "TicTacToeButton1", "TicTacToeButton2",..."TicTacToeButton9" then to get a reference to it, just Me.Controls.Find("TicTacToeButton" & RandomButton) and Cast it to Button

Comment: Let me reword my question a bit. I wanted to know if I could disable a button using a enum. I have no problem disabling the button using the command "btn2.enabled = False".

Comment: Yes, but you have to get a reference to the button before you can access its .Enabled property, or any other property.  Use Me.Controls.Find(String) to do that.

Comment: Assign your buttons to a List<of Button> or an Array of Buttons. Then use your Enum to index the button that you want.