# Why don't my Labels show in VB.NET Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312239/how-to-programmatically-add-controls-to-a-form-n-vb-net) question, I wrote some code to create a label for each attribute of an xml element.

The problem is that when I run the project, my form only displays the first label. I've checked in the immediate window as well as debug window and all of the labels are loaded to the form, but none of them are displayed. Help?

Here's the code that runs when the form loads.

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("xmlfile")
Dim ability As XmlNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ability").Item(0)
Dim numberofLabels = ability.Attributes.Count
ReDim labels(numberofLabels)
For counter As Integer = 0 To numberofLabels - 1
    labels(counter) = New Label
    labels(counter).Visible = True
    labels(counter).Text = ability.Attributes.Item(counter).Name
    labels(counter).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 30 + counter * 10)
    Me.Controls.Add(labels(counter))
Next
```

Comment: the array is not really needed, if you give them a good name or tag them you can find them in the Controls collection quite easily.  Try: `Dim labels(counter) As New Label`

Comment: counter * 10 was a guess.  That guess doesn't always work out well, things go badly when it is too low and all of these labels overlap each other.  Which will certainly happen on a "retina" display.  Don't guess, use the label's Height property.  *After* you added it.

Comment: The positioning could also be done smoothly by adding the labels not to the form but to a FlowLayoutPanel. Also try setting the label's names to something like ´"lblXMLAttrib" & counter.ToString´

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using some layout manager, to help you with control positioning. Doing it manually is not worth the pain. Try using `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel`. Both can be docked or anchored to a parent control, so everything behaves very smoothly. Otherwise you are looking to write a lot of positioning/resizing code, and then maintaining it later.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of 10 in the original code line for a new point to a bigger value such as 40, so that new labels could appear separated visually:

```
labels(counter).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10 + counter, 30 + counter * 40)
```