# Adding picture boxes dynamically in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, runtime, picturebox

I'm sure there is someone out there who can explain this clearly.

I would have assumed that I could simply use:

```
Dim pb As PictureBox
```

then I could use

```
pb = New PictureBox
```

but apparently not.

I would also assume I can set parameters

```
pb.Width
pb.Height
pb.Top
pb.Left
```

etc.

If anyone can help me create a picture box dynamically where I can set the properties I would be so grateful, thanks.

I'm also sorry if this question has already been asked, but I have been looking for a few hours now and nothing has worked for me.

Comment: In what way doesn't this work? That is exactly how you create a picture box.

Comment: WozzecC is correct, that is how i do it aswell. And if it doesn't work. Could you at least give the errormessage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically add controls to a form in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312239/how-to-programmatically-add-controls-to-a-form-in-vb-net)

Comment: And just to make sure... are you adding the picturebox somewhere that you can see it after you declare it and set it's properties?  And is the code firing at all (put a stop on it and see if your processing hits it)?

Comment: Also, are you setting one of the pictureBox's Image properties?  Without that, you can add it all you want, but you probably won't see it during runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other words, you are trying to add a control to a windows form programmatically. Of course I don't know what you have tried, but I would use:

```
Dim pb As New PictureBox
pb.Width = 100 'or whatever
pb.Height = 200
pb.Top = 50 'or whatever
pb.Left = 50
pb.ImageLocation = "dog.png"
Me.Controls.Add(pb)
```