# How to add buttons dynamically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi , i have to add buttons dynamically. based on one of the column in the table. i had a column resource. i have to add buttons dynamically based on the distinct data of the  resource column of the table the table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312239/how-to-programmatically-add-controls-to-a-form-in-vb-net

Comment: Hi its a different one