# Create Buttons depending on recordcount

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

i'm developing a project for a POS based touch screen
and i want to know how to add buttons at run time depending on Items count stored in a database
and how can that buttons be aligned and displayed in Container (Panel or FlowlayoutPanel) ?
this code i used it to create a button:

```
    Dim newbtn As New Button
    Me.Controls.Add(newbtn)
    AddHandler newbtn.Click, AddressOf newbtn_mouseup
```

Comment: Please view [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312239/how-to-programmatically-add-controls-to-a-form-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1):

actualy i found this solution:

```
    If Cn.State = 1 Then Cn.Close()
    If Rs.State = 1 Then Rs.Close()
    Cn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\rptdb.mdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=KNOZ1003")
    Rs.Open("Select * From tblunit ", Cn, 1, 2)

    For i = 1 To Rs.RecordCount
        Dim newbtn As New Button
        newbtn.Text = Rs.Fields("unm").Value
        newbtn.Size = New Size(100, 50)
        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newbtn)
        Rs.MoveNext()
    Next
```