# Dynamic control of textbox and checkbox based of SQL query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm currently working on project of creating examination system.
I'm using Vb.net and MySQL for data.
My question is ( I HAVE 0 experience with dynamic controls ) how to dynamicly create one textbox and 3 checkboxes based on data from SQL.

Sample :

```
SELECT Question, AnswerA, AnswerB, AnswerC 
from TBL_Test_QA 
WHERE `GROUP` = '' and `Subgroup` = ''
```

and query gives me 10 Questions. So basically i need 10 textboxes and 30 checkboxes. Can You guys help me figuring out the code.

If You need more information please ask and I'll give it.

Comment: As it was proposed to you please take the time to go through the [tour] and also read [ask]

Comment: furthermore you would use a loop for every question and use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312239/how-to-programmatically-add-controls-to-a-form-in-vb-net

Comment: Try to explore your needs.. There's a lot of possible solution outside.

Comment: @Mederic Thank You for Youre guide and thank you for help.