# Code to add menu strip items and sub items from SQL stored procedure

Tags: vb.net, menu, dropdown, menustrip

I need Vb.net code to add menustrip items and sub items dynamically from SQL database, and how can I write the click event code for each menu I don't know it's name before loading from database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically add controls to a form in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312239/how-to-programmatically-add-controls-to-a-form-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

thank you, i handled it using the below code :

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    ' Dim MenuStrip1 As New MenuStrip
    Dim oMenu1 As New ToolStripMenuItem

    With MenuStrip1.Items.Add("Set As Next Track")
        .Tag = 1
        ' AddHandler .Click, AddressOf lvTracksContextMenu_Click
    End With

    With MenuStrip1.Items.Add("&Loop Track")
        .Tag = 2
        AddHandler .Click, AddressOf lvTracksContextMenu_Click
    End With


    With oMenu1
        oMenu1.Name = "QuickQueue SubMenu"
        oMenu1.Text = "QuickQueue"
        AddHandler .Click, AddressOf lvTracksContextMenu_Click

        With .DropDownItems.Add("Item 1")
            .Tag = 101
            AddHandler .Click, AddressOf lvTracksContextMenu_Click
        End With
        With .DropDownItems.Add("Item 2")
            .Tag = 102
            AddHandler .Click, AddressOf lvTracksContextMenu_Click
        End With
        With .DropDownItems.Add("Item 3")
            .Tag = 103
            AddHandler .Click, AddressOf lvTracksContextMenu_Click
        End With
    End With
    MenuStrip1.Items.Add(oMenu1)

    'oLVTracksMenu.Show(New System.Drawing.Point(e.X + Me.Left, e.Y + Me.Top))

End Sub

Sub lvTracksContextMenu_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show(CType(sender, ToolStripItem).Tag)
End Sub
```

End Class