# Is there a way to add a button to a form with a user defined name and then also generate a handler for said button

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create an app that will allow a user to add buttons with a provided name to a form. However, I am unsure how to create the button using the user-provided value.

I have tried this

```
Dim Button_ & ButtonName As New Button
```

This obviously does not work, does anyone know if this is possible and if so, how I would go about doing it.

I would also need to generate a handler for the button so that I can make it function.
For example,

```
Private Sub button_ & ButtonName & _Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_ & ButtonName & .Click
```

Comment: Why would the user care what the name of a control is? The name of a control is only used in code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312239/how-to-programmatically-add-controls-to-a-form-in-vb-net Just Google "add a control to a form in vb.net"

Comment: `dim btn as new Button() with { .Name = ButtonName, .Text = ButtonName } AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf SomePredefinedHandler`. Or use a Lambda: `AddHandler btn.Click, Sub(obj, args)  End Sub` (`End Sub` goes on a new line). Better use the first `AddHandler` syntax. You probably want to add these controls to a collection (e.g., `List(Of Button)`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with:

```
Dim btn1 As New Button With {
    'Write properties here.
    .Size = New Drawing.Size(10, 10),
    .Visible = True
}

AddHandler btn1.Click, New EventHandler(AddressOf btn1_Click)
Me.Controls.Add(btn1)
```

And then you create the sub that manages the event:

```
Friend Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Write code here.
End Sub
```